# How to create an Ivy dependency for a jar inside a zip archive?

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I'm converting a project from Java 8 to Java 11 (a future conversion to Java 17 or later is deep in the backlog).  Some components depend on `jaxb` and `jaxws`, which I have learned were removed.

Thanks to quite a few other articles I have learned to add the `jaxb` and `jaxws` dependencies explicitly.  Now I have come across an odd case.

I have one module that uses package `javax.jws` and class `javax.jws.WebService`.  My development environment has `jaxws-ri.zip` version 2.3.6.  This contains `jaxws-rt.jar`.  Our repo also has `jaxws-rt` version 2.1.7, which I am already including in the dependency list.

I have the following snippets in the module's `ivy.xml` file:

```
<dependency org="com.sun.xml.ws" name="jaxws-rt" rev="2.1.7" transitive="false" />
<dependency org="com.sun.xml.ws" name="jaxws-ri" rev="2.3.6">
  <artifact name="jaxws-ri" type="zip" />
</dependency>
```

`jaxws-ri.zip` extracts at compile time into the module subdirectory `dependency/java/jaxws-ri/jaxws-ri`.  The `lib` directory then contains `jaxws-rt.jar`.  I was able to use this version of the jar to pre-compile generated Java classes.  Now I need to use this version **from the zip archive** instead of the repository to compile the module.

So.  How do I build this module using **this** version of `jaxws-rt.jar` (or if needed other jars from the zip archive) instead of the repo's version?